# Check if Seleniums chrome webbrowser is downloading

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've seen a few questions asking if it's possible to check if a specific download is completed, or if a specific download has been completed successfully. (to which the answer appears to be no.)

What I want to know: Is it possible to see if selenium is currently downloading *any* file? I.e. it doesn't matter if it's one file, or 20. Something like a small boolean check would be ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When chrome is downloading a file you can check your downloads folder for the temp file (*`.crdownload`) that Chrome uses. When the download finishes that file is "replaced" by the actual filename/type.

```
/// <summary>
/// Looks for a file with the given extension (Example: "*.crdownload") in the current user's "Download" folder.
/// </summary>
public static string LocateDownloadedFile(string fileExtension)
{
    // Get the default downloads folder for the current user
    string downloadFolderPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile) + "\\Downloads";
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(downloadFolderPath);
    FileInfo[] filesFound = di.GetFiles(fileExtension);
    if (filesFound.Length == 0)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
    else
    {
        // do other stuff
    }
}
```